# Texlive package list - svn or git

Tags: texlive

I looked into several answers here but didn't quite find an answer to what I was looking for. I have `texlive-2021` installed on a OpenSuse. Checking the package `tools` installed in my `/usr/share` folder I found that all files are dated by Feb 2020.

To my understanding there is a yearly release for `texlive`. Where do I find a list which packages were supposed to be included?

More or less the question how to check what was supposed and what is :-/

Comment: You are using the opensuse repackaged version of texlive so you would need to use your linux package manager tools (sorry I don't know what opensuse uses)  to see what files are in the suse texlive2021 package. The listings of upstream texlive 2021 from TUG will not be that useful.

Comment: Thx for your response. To some extent I'm aware about zypper and checking. Nevertheless since the "tools" project seems quite in a strange status I wanted to check what was distributed with texlive-2021. But I cannot find any hints about the sources for texlive - and even on a historical scale, e. g. what was released in April 2021 and what is now, etc. etc.